# trigger mysql unknown table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've been trying to solve this problem. Here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON table_a
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE tname VARCHAR(20);
     IF (table_a.field_offer=1) THEN
      SET tname='table_b';
    ELSEIF (table_a.field_offer=0) THEN
      SET tname='table_c'; 
    END IF;   
      IF ((new.field_state = 0)) THEN
       UPDATE tname join table_a on tname.ID=table_a.ref_field
       SET tname.STOCK = tname.STOCK -1;
      ELSEIF ((new.field_state = 1)) THEN
       UPDATE tname join table_a on tname.ID=table_a.ref_field
       SET tname.STOCK = tname.STOCK +1;
      END IF;  
    END;
```

I am getting:

> Unknown table 'table_a' in field list. Field_offer and field_state can
>   be null.

Comment: You should be accessing current value in a table inside a trigger function with NEW and OLD.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you also can't use a variable (such as `tname`) AS a table name in a query.

Answer (score 1):

I've shown below what was said in the comments to the question:

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON table_a
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE tname VARCHAR(20);
    IF (NEW.field_offer=1) THEN
       UPDATE `table_b` 
       SET STOCK = CASE NEW.field_state 
                   WHEN 0 THEN STOCK - 1 
                   WHEN 1 THEN STOCK + 1 
                   ELSE STOCK 
                   END
       WHERE ID=NEW.ref_field
       ;
    ELSEIF (NEW.field_offer=0) THEN
       UPDATE `table_c` 
       SET STOCK = CASE NEW.field_state 
                   WHEN 0 THEN STOCK - 1 
                   WHEN 1 THEN STOCK + 1 
                   ELSE STOCK 
                   END
       WHERE ID=NEW.ref_field
       ;
    END IF;
    ...
```

Note that I changed the updates from `UPDATE ... JOIN` as MySQL does not allow you to change the data of the triggered table; while you were not actually updating table_a, the JOIN could have been enough for MySQL to have objected... that and the joins would've updated every row in `table_b/c` that had a match in `table_a`, not just `table_a` rows related to the values in or row of the trigger.